# UTM to WGS84 in C

Tags: c, utm, wgs84

I am trying to convert coordinates from **UTM** to **WGS84/(LatLon)** in C language.

I found this similar thread: [How to convert from UTM to LatLng in python or Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343865/how-to-convert-from-utm-to-latlng-in-python-or-javascript#)

However, when converting the code, the latitude is correct, but the longitude is way off.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

// Input
double east = 724197;           // Easting
double north = 6175457;         // Northing
double utmZone = 32;            // UTM zone
double FalseNorth = 0;          // Northern hemisphere:  FalseNorth = 0;
                                // Southern hemisphere:  FalseNorth = 10000000;
// Constants (WGS84 datum)
double SemiMajor = 6378137;     // Ellipsoidal semi-major axis (Meters)
double FalseEast = 500000;      // UTM East bias (Meters)
double ScaleFactor = 0.9996;    // Scale at natural origin

double LngOrigin = utmZone * 6 - 183;   // Reference meridian of longitude

double Ecc = 0.081819190842622;         // Eccentricity
double EccSq = Ecc * Ecc;
double Ecc2Sq = EccSq / (1. - EccSq);
double Ecc2 = sqrt(Ecc2Sq);             // Secondary eccentricity
double E1 = ( 1 - sqrt(1-EccSq) ) / ( 1 + sqrt(1-EccSq) );
double E12 = E1 * E1;
double E13 = E12 * E1;
double E14 = E13 * E1;

// Output
double result_lat;            // Latitude in WGS84
double result_lon;            // Longitude in WGS84

// Calculate the Cassini projection parameters
double M1 = (north - FalseNorth) / ScaleFactor;
double Mu1 = M1 / ( SemiMajor * (1 - EccSq/4.0 - 3.0*EccSq*EccSq/64.0 -
                    5.0*EccSq*EccSq*EccSq/256.0) );

double Phi1 = Mu1   + (3.0*E1/2.0 - 27.0*E13/32.0)      * sin(2.0*Mu1)
                    + (21.0*E12/16.0 - 55.0*E14/32.0)   * sin(4.0*Mu1)
                    + (151.0*E13/96.0)                  * sin(6.0*Mu1)
                    + (1097.0*E14/512.0)                * sin(8.0*Mu1);

double sin2phi1 = sin(Phi1) * sin(Phi1);
double Rho1 = (SemiMajor * (1.0-EccSq) ) / pow(1.0-EccSq*sin2phi1,1.5);
double Nu1 = SemiMajor / sqrt(1.0-EccSq*sin2phi1);

// Compute parameters as defined in the POSC specification.  T, C and D
double T1 = tan(Phi1) * tan(Phi1);
double T12 = T1 * T1;
double C1 = Ecc2Sq * cos(Phi1) * cos(Phi1);
double C12 = C1 * C1;
double D  = (east - FalseEast) / (ScaleFactor * Nu1);
double D2 = D * D;
double D3 = D2 * D;
double D4 = D3 * D;
double D5 = D4 * D;
double D6 = D5 * D;

// Compute the Latitude and Longitude and convert to degrees
double lat = Phi1 - Nu1*tan(Phi1)/Rho1 *
                    ( D2/2.0 - (5.0 + 3.0*T1 + 10.0*C1 - 4.0*C12 - 9.0*Ecc2Sq)*D4/24.0
                    + (61.0 + 90.0*T1 + 298.0*C1 + 45.0*T12 - 252.0*Ecc2Sq - 3.0*C12)*D6/720.0);

result_lat = (lat * 180.0 / M_PI);

double lon = LngOrigin + 
                    ( D - (1.0 + 2.0*T1 + C1)*D3/6.0
                    + (5.0 - 2.0*C1 + 28.0*T1 - 3.0*C12 + 8.0*Ecc2Sq + 24.0*T12)*D5/120.0) / cos(Phi1);

result_lon = (lon * 180.0 / M_PI);

printf("result_lat = %lf\n", result_lat);
printf("result_lon = %lf\n", result_lon);

return 0;
}
```

**Result**

```
result_lat = 55.673059
result_lon = 519.227573
```

I expected `result_lon` to be close to `12.56`

Comment: `printf` `%lf` is equivalent to just `%f` in C99. In C89 it has undefined behavior.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe the the original code you translated was correct? Did you run that JavaScript code to see if it gave the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the classic PROJ API (now [deprecated](https://proj.org/development/index.html)), shown here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <proj_api.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    projPJ pj_utm, pj_latlong;
    char utm_s[50];
    double x = 724197.0;
    double y = 6175457.0;
    int zone = 32;
    sprintf(utm_s, "+proj=utm +zone=%d", zone);
    pj_utm = pj_init_plus(utm_s);
    pj_latlong = pj_init_plus("+proj=latlong");
    pj_transform(pj_utm, pj_latlong, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL );
    x *= RAD_TO_DEG;
    y *= RAD_TO_DEG;
    printf("result (lat, lon) = (%f, %f)\n", y, x);
    pj_free(pj_utm);
    pj_free(pj_latlong);
    return 0;
}
```

Or modern PROJ (since version 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <proj.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    proj_log_level(PJ_DEFAULT_CTX, PJ_LOG_TRACE);
    PJ *P;
    PJ_COORD c, c_out;
    int zone = 32;
    char utm_s[50];
    sprintf(utm_s, "+proj=utm +zone=%d", zone);
    P = proj_create_crs_to_crs(
        PJ_DEFAULT_CTX, utm_s, "+proj=latlong", NULL);
    if (P==0)
        return 1;
    c.xy.x = 724197.0;
    c.xy.y = 6175457.0;
    c_out = proj_trans(P, PJ_FWD, c);
    printf("result (lat, lon) = (%f, %f)\n", c_out.lp.phi, c_out.lp.lam);
    proj_destroy(P);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile, link (assuming you have libproj.so somewhere) and run it:

```
$ gcc code.c -lproj
$ ./a.out
result (lat, lon) = (55.673059, 12.565558)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double LngOrigin = (utmZone - 1) * 6 - 180 + 3; //deg;   // Reference meridian of longitude
LngOrigin*=M_PI/180;
```

`EccSq` will be constant.
With corrected reference meridian everything works as intended.
Used to check WGS84 to UTM conversion

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Are you sure this does actually answer the question at the top of the page, and isn't a comment or a way to thank another answer? Read [answer] and [edit] your post to clarify why this is indeed an answer.