# How to convert from UTM with Down to LatLng with Altitude in python or Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, gis

I found answer for converting UTM to LatLong [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/343865/3125070)

```
(lat,lng) = transform(easting, northing, zone)
```

Most answers I search does not include calculations to compute altitude from down. But, I want to convert down measurements to altitude, how do I do something like:

```
(lat, lng, alt) = transform(easting,        northing,       down,           zone)
(?  , ?  , ?  ) = transform(5735847.026821, 619997.428877,  -116.869707,    "30U")
```

Comment: UTM is just a horizontal representation, that doesn't care about altitude. You could extend altitude to your coordinates using [srtm.py](https://github.com/tkrajina/srtm.py)

Comment: That should be handy when we don't have any altitude measurements, but the measurements I have are recorded in a car and I want to visualize the trajectory. I guess there will be loss of information doing that as that would not retrieve the actual y of the car.